# in VI mode i want copy particular specific lines from. log, .txt file

Tags: vim, grep

I have files which contain more than 2,00,000 lines in file i. e. abc.log file in that I want to copy line 600 to 750  and 40,000 to 60,000 in VI mode and paste new txt files

Comment: You could use **sed** instead of vi.  Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47298469/how-to-copy-lines-10-to-15-of-a-file-into-another-file-in-unix

Answer (score 1):

In normal mode (use <kbd>Esc</kbd> if you are currently in insert mode)

```
:600,750w new_file_name1
```

and

```
:40000,60000w new_file_name2
```